# More on Threads and Processes Using Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, process, resources

This [article](http://www.seti.net/SETINet/Other/Threads/Chap%201/Ch1.htm) about what are threads and first defines a procces reads

"The operating system provides this virtualisation. Processes execute modules of code. 
These may be disjoint; in the sense that, the executable modules of code comprising Windows Explorer 
and Microsoft Word are disjoint. However, they may also be shared, as in the case of DLL's, the code 
for which is typically being executed in the context of many different processes, often simultaneously. 
The execution speed or ordering of processes is normally independent of one another: Microsoft word does 
not stop opening a document just because the print spooler is currently sending something to the printer! "

I explain the article reads that "just because the print spooler is currently sending something to the printer! "

I got a respocne that "It doesn't stop popening the doc just becuase the print spool 
because opening a document and spooling the printer are different processes"

it was further explained that

"yes basically two programs may be using one DLL
but they are still separate processes
so one process may have multiple threads
like when you go to task manager, you can look at processes
Each process gets their own turn on the CPU"

I wanted more clarification about it and got

"They are just saying that the DLL can be executed by multiple things simultaneously.
The code for a DLL is typically being executed in the context of many different processes, often simultaneously
that's the key line"

and "two processes both using the same DLL (lets say "interpretdocument.dll") can both execute at the same time. they do not have to wait for one to "finish" with the dll
in many other cases things that share resources would have to do that. One does not stop the other"

Then I explained it is not technically running simultaneously but flip flopping

and finally got to the point I didin't get: the individual responded:

"right but it doesn't hold the resource if it did that then the entire process of opening the document would have to complete, then it would release the DLL then the printer could start using it
like trying to rename a document when its open
I assume... you're reading the book, not me :)"

My question is, what does this mean "but it doesn't hold the resources, is the resource the DLL or the .doc file, and why was it emphasized? they share the resource?

Comment: How is this related to Java and Android? And where did you get the responses you are quoting? The best way to get answers about what someone meant is to ask them, and the best place for that is where the original discussion took place. Or at least provide a link.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov This conversation was in the Android chat between 16:00 and 18:00 today. It relates to Android becuase I am learning more about what Threads and Process are and how they differ because Android used them.

Comment: This is in no way obvious from the original question. Additionally, learning about Java/Android from an article about Delphi might not be the best idea. Something like the Java Tutorial might give you a better start.

Comment: 'Then I explained it is not technically running simultaneously but flip flopping' - well that's a little 'off'. If there are 4 cores running the DLL code from their own L1 cache, that's pretty simultaneous!  Also, there seems to be some confusion between code and other data.  Most DLL are primarily code-based and, as such, are completely shareable between threads/processes - code does not change, (hopefully!).

Comment: So is the resources he is talking about the Word Document or the DLL? I am guessing the document... @NikolayElenkov I want to learn what a thread is INITIALLY NOT in terms of a language but in general. I am trying to sort out gopod articles from this standpoint.